# array of all elements in different associations that belong to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where an admin can ask a question. It can be assigned to a company, group (segment of company), or a specific user.

Now what I'm trying to do is get all the questions that can be associated with a user. This means if the user is a part of a group, then the question in that group is also for that user.

The way I've tried to do this is, is:

```
<% personal_questions = current_user.questions %>

<% group_questions = [] %>
<% current_user.groups.each do |group| %>
  <% group_questions.push(group.questions) %>
<% end %>

<% all_questions = personal_questions + group_questions %>

<%=  all_questions.map(&:name) %>
```

now it seems to fail to print out all the questions, it prints out the personal questions, but for group it just states "Questions" when I map them out.

my associations are:

User:

```
  # groups
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships
  # question
  has_many :question_participants, as: :questionable
  has_many :questions, through: :question_participants
```

Question:

```
 has_many :users, through: :question_participants,
                   source: :questionable, source_type: 'User'
  has_many :groups, through: :question_participants,
                    source: :questionable, source_type: 'Group'
```

Group:

```
  # users
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
  # questions
  has_many :question_participants, as: :questionable
  has_many :questions, through: :question_participants
```

The goal is essentially to get an array of all questions that belongs to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is happening because the result array is a mix of questions and arrays of questions.

I would do this:

```
all_questions = (current_user.questions + current_user.groups.map(&:questions).flatten).uniq
```